# Intersected array to generate width and left

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

```
const repeatTimeDict = { 
  '0': ['1'],
  '1': ['0'],
  '5': ['6', '7', '8'],
  '6': ['5', '7', '8'],
  '7': ['5', '6', '8'],
  '8': ['5', '6', '7', '9', '10'],
  '9': ['8', '10'],
  '10': ['8', '9']
}
```

Above data means '0' key intersected with '1' and '5' key intersected with '8', '7', '6' and so on.

```
const res = {
  '0': { 'left': 0, 'width': 50 },
  '1': { 'left': 50, 'width': 50 },
  '5': { 'left': 0, 'width': 25 },
  '6': { 'left': 25, 'width': 25 },
  '7': { 'left': 50, 'width': 25 },
  '8': { 'left', 75, 'width': 25 },
  '9': { 'left': 0, 'width': 37.5 }, // (100 - 25) / 2
  '10': { 'left': 37.5. 'width': 37.5 }
}
```

Above is the result I want to generate. '8' key intersected with '7', '6', '5' and '9', but '9' key doesn't intersected with '5', '6' and '7'. I stuck in '8' key's situation, because it involve in two group. **Does anyone know the good algorithm or idea to solve this question?** (BTW, I delete the solution I have done before, because that part will confuse people.)

```
// This is the graph I want to generate through the repeatTimeDict
5  6  7  8
|| || || ||
|| || || ||
   || || ||
         ||
         ||
|  ||  | ||
 9   10  ||
```

Comment: Please include whatever you have done so far

Comment: Ok, @RifatBinReza, I shared my solution, but it involve the real data situation, I can't shared that part, so I give you a sample data.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand the requirements.  Why is that the expected output any better than if `8`, `9`, and `10` each has width `33.33` and `5`, `6`, and `7` have width `(100 - 33.33) / 3` (`22.22`)`.  They seem equally likely to me, so how do you decide?

Comment: We don't know what answer you expect to that unsolved question, so we cannot suggest an algorithm for it. What is the desired outcome, and why? What does this data represent, what are you trying to do there?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Because 8 intersected with two group [5, 6, 7] and [9, 10]. I have to figure out 8 key's width and left. So in [5, 6, 7] situation 8 key's left is 75 and width is 25, but [9, 10] situation 8 key's width is 33.33, bigger then 25, I have to abandon 33.33 and use 25 to be the correct width and regenerate [9, 10] situation's width and left value.

Comment: Understood, but why do you calculate the `[5, 6,7, 8]` group first and the `[8, 9, 10]` afterward?  Why not the reverse?

Comment: @Bergi, I delete the solution I have done before, that part will confused people. So if just the data and result part. Will it be clearer?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Because in real data 10 is not the end, you choose reverse or not, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @PoWenChen I still don't get how you arrive at the result for #8 - as you say, it's involved in two groups, do you just want to ignore the second one? And where does `(100 - 25) / 2` come from?

Comment: I think there are communication issues here.  Your input data is described as an object, which is a inherently unordered data structure.  So are the actual numeric values important (because `7 < 9`) or is the group size important `{5, 6, 7, 8}` has four elements and `{8, 9, 10}` has only three?  Or if neither, how do you decide?

Comment: @Bergi I draw the graph, maybe that will make you more clearer what I want to show on the screen. Because in react or vue if you want to show something on the screen, it just depend on the data. In my situation I want to show 9 and 10's column like graph. So `(100 - 25) / 2` is what I want in this situation.

Comment: @Bergi: I think the `(100 - 25)` is because `8` already got `25%` based on the `{5, 6, 7, 8}` group, so there is only `75%` left to split for the remaining two of the `{8, 9, 10}` group.  Hence `(100 - 25) / 2` for each of `{9, 10}`.

Comment: Where's the actual JavaScript that you've tried to use?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I use group size to decide width and left.

Comment: @zer00ne, sorry, that part will confuse people, so I delete that part. ; (

Comment: So it gets 25% because the largest group it's part of has four members?  But even that is not clear in more complex scenarios.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I use group size to determine width and generate left, and because 8 cover whole [5, 6, 7] so I have to make 8 to be the most right part.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't really understand what you're looking for.  Bergi's solution may be what you want, but if it's not, please add at least one more example.  But I'm going to bed now, and may or may not have time to look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's ok, thank you. ;) Maybe I need to think another way to ask question. BTW, I apologize my poor English that make you confused.

Comment: It's no problem at all.  I stuck with it because I suspect there's an interesting question in there, but I can't understand all the ramifications.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a greedy fill, each group taking 100% space together. It's assigned in ascending order.

```
const res = {};
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  if (!(i in repeatTimeDict)) continue;
  if (i in res) continue;
  const repeatTime = [i, ...repeatTimeDict[i]].sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  let space = 100;
  let count = repeatTime.length;
  for (const j of repeatTime) {
    if (j in res) {
      space -= res[j].width;
      count--;
    }
  }
  const width = space / count;
  let left = 0;
  for (const j of repeatTime) {
    if (j in res) continue;
    res[j] = {left, width};
    left += width;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's that "ascending order" which is bothering me.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Still it seems to be what the OP wants, as he never stated otherwise (and a non-greedy algorithm would be much more complicated :-P)

Comment: Oh yes, it definitely seems like a greedy algorithm here.  I just am bothered by the question I can't seem to get answered in the comments.  It seems unlikely that the numeric values are inherently important and that they could be replaced with `A', 'B', ..., 'H' just as well, but with the input being an unordered structure, I simply don't have a reason to prefer object key order over any other.

Comment: @ScottSauyet True - that's why I kept my solution as generic as possible, you can choose a different order just by replacing the `for (let i=0; i<10; i++)` with `for (const i of "ABCDEFGH")` or whatever.

Comment: @ScottSauyet First, thank's for your sharing, ;) but in my situation, your 8 will be { left: 25, width: 25 }. That's not want I want. Width value is correct but left value is not correct.

Comment: @PoWenChen: Should that have been directed at Bergi?  I haven't offered a solution, since I still really don't understand the requirements.

Comment: @PoWenChen I had not realised the values in your arrays were not sorted properly. Easy to fix…

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I realized your concern. Yes, I didn't sort the array's value in repeatTimeDict. Sorry my English is not very well. ; (

Comment: @Bergi, thank you, I sorted my repeatTimeDict and your answer is correct. ;)